# Force side-by-side minipages equally into margins

Tags: floats, margins, minipage

I have two separate figures which I want side-by-side, but they don't quite fit into the `\textwidth`, and rather than flow into the margins slightly the one on the right just overlaps the one on the left.

My raw code at the moment:

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{figs/blah}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{figs/blah2}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

I've tried two methods so far to get overlap into the margins.
I loaded the `adjustbox` option with the `export` option and put

```
[width=1.2\textwidth,center]
```

after `\begin{figure}`.

And I'm using the `memoir` class so also tried replacing `\centering` with `\centerfloat` (in the figure, not in the minipages).

Neither worked.

I pretty much want to change priorities so that the figure borders are sacrosanct and the margins aren't, rather than the opposite as it is now.  Or at least, at the moment the left-hand figure's right-hand border is currently being infringed rather than the left-hand margin.

Answer (score 2):

`\centering` can not do anything to a block that is already full width.  A `minipage` is just positioned like a big letter so you can use the same mechanisms, for example:

```
\begin{figure}
  \hspace*{-.1\textwidth}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{figs/blah}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{figs/blah2}
  \end{minipage}%
  \hspace*{-.1\textwidth}%
\end{figure}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks. Although I'm not sure what you mean by "big letter"?

Comment: @user3087409 I mean `minipage` has no special positioning logic, two minipages are positioned like two letters `XY` if you put them with no space they come side by side, if you put a blank line in between they are in separate paragraphs one above the other, etc